# SQL Server: Create sequence column based on a non-distinct column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if I'm asking this question right, but hopefully I can explain it well enough. I have a table that has a Date, Value, and WeekEndDate column. I want to create a sequence column that counts the  distinct weeks from 1-13 and cycles every 13 weeks.

I attached a small sample of the output I'm trying to create. Is this even possible?

[image: Desired Table Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()` and some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       ((dense_rank() over (order by weekEnd) - 1) % 13) + 1
from t;
```